# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) in PyCharm, RESTART: Shell in IDLE, and closes console

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, ctree

I'm trying to connect c-TreeSQL using Python.  I know I have the correct driver because I can connect using [George Poulose's Query Tool](https://www.gpoulose.com/)

I have tried these variations and each one has crashed;

```
import pyodbc

## Instructions from http://doc.4d.com/4Dv17/4D/17/Using-a-connection-string.200-3786162.en.html
# conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={c-treeACE ODBC Driver};Host=<Host from driver config>;UID=<User name>;PWD=<Password>;DATABASE=liveSQL;')

# Connection string from Query Tool
# conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={c-treeACE ODBC Driver};ODBC;DSN=DOTLIVEREP;Host=<Host from driver config>;UID=<User name>;PWD=<Password>;DATABASE=liveSQL;SERVICE=6597 ;CHARSET NAME=;MAXROWS=;OPTIONS=;;PRSRVCUR=OFF;;FILEDSN=;SAVEFILE=;FETCH_SIZE=;QUERY_TIMEOUT=;SCROLLCUR=OFF;')

# Connection string from Query Tool. Added driver parameter
conn = pyodbc.connect('ODBC;DSN=DOTLIVEREP;Host=<Host from driver config>;UID=<User name>;PWD=<Password>;DATABASE=liveSQL;SERVICE=6597 ;CHARSET NAME=;MAXROWS=;OPTIONS=;;PRSRVCUR=OFF;;FILEDSN=;SAVEFILE=;FETCH_SIZE=;QUERY_TIMEOUT=;SCROLLCUR=OFF;')


print('Success')
```

Each one of these connection strings causes a crash in PyCharm, IDLE, and the console.

I'm not sure what would be causing this

Answer (score 0):

you should change the field in the connection string where is  for the specific value of your application.

For example here, instead of < Host from driver config >. Lets say your host is MYHOST. You should put MYHOST. Same thing for < User name >, you should put your username, like jacob, and so on. Normally these field with brackets are the on you have put a value:

```
# Connection string from Query Tool. Added driver parameter
conn = pyodbc.connect('ODBC;DSN=DOTLIVEREP;Host=MYHOST;UID=jacob;PWD=<Password>;DATABASE=liveSQL;SERVICE=6597 ;CHARSET NAME=;MAXROWS=;OPTIONS=;;PRSRVCUR=OFF;;FILEDSN=;SAVEFILE=;FETCH_SIZE=;QUERY_TIMEOUT=;SCROLLCUR=OFF;')
```

Answer (score 0):

Even tho I haven't had the same issue like you had, here's my fix for the error while using **pyodbc** and **MS SQL Server**:

I tried to connect to multiple databases on the **same** server right at the beginning of my code. When I tried connecting to a second database on the **same** server, my code threw this error.

What I did to fix it was to close my first connection to the server before, do the work that needed to be done, and close the connection afterwords. Then I connected to my second database and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has been smashing their head against the wall for hours on this one, just use the ODBC library instead of the PyODBC library: once you use ODBC.odbc() to connect with the exact same connection string, everything works.

I have no idea what it is with the c-tree driver VS PyODBC library (my client used Attache and it was using a variation of the c-tree driver to connect, the driver is 32 bit but not sure if that's part of the issue since I also use 32 bit Python), it just makes the Python.exe crash as soon as it connects in my case.

Comment: What is this "ODBC library"? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @gord-thompson Apologies for the semantics, I think it’s more accurate to call it module: this ODBC module is part of the pywin32 package of Python distribution, you can look up for more details here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC